# Unable to create new directory using NSFileManager with with the owner as `root`

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

Assignment of `NSFileOwnerAccountName` and `NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName` does not work? The directory created defaults to my account `coderama` and the group `staff`.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSMutableDictionary *attr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; 
[attr setObject:@"root" forKey:NSFileOwnerAccountName];
[attr setObject:@"wheel" forKey:NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName]; 
[attr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0755] forKey:NSFilePosixPermissions];

[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:dir withIntermediateDirectories:TRUE attributes:attr error:&error];
```

Comment: What information does error contain?

Comment: Oh. Well, according to your code sample, you didn't seem to be checking it, or even checking the BOOL result. But if you're really not getting anything in error, then try errno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly likely that without authorization, you will be unable to create anything owned by root. However, assuming you *do* have authorization…

The docs don't mention this restriction specifically for `createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:`, but for the related method `setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:`, you can't use `NSFileOwnerAccountName` or `NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName`. You must use the account ID instead, with `NSFileOwnerAccountID` and `NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID`. If you use the `…Name`-based keys, they are ignored.

It may be that `createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:` also has this restriction. I would try setting IDs instead of names, which I suspect will work.